# I'm new to flutter and I'm keep getting this error

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgbYI.png)

help me to fix this up  don't know what's wrong with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a spacing issue. Pubspec YAML file is very critical with indentations so check this document and set up the spacing properly.

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/pubspec

Comment: Most Welcome :) If you are new to flutter you may like some of my designs to have a reference https://github.com/daymamanish.